# Can't access multiple records being returned by sql via ADODB.Recordset object

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

When I execut the sql direct it returns 4 records. when I execute the `oraCommand.Execute` the `oraResults` object shows only 1 record returned it should have a count of 4. 
Hence I can get the value and name for the single record. Question is how do I get the other 3 records? I have tried `set oraResults=oraResults.NextRecordSet()` and I get error saying not supported!

Any help will appreciated.

This is the snippet of the code:

```
set oraCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
'set connection and sql statement
set oraCommand.ActiveConnection = oraConnection
oraCommand.CommandText =oraSQLStatement
oraCommand.CommandType = 1 ' commandText
oraCommand.Prepared = True   

set oraResults = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
'run the sql 
set oraResults = oraCommand.Execute
oraResults.Fields(0).Name    - Name from first record is returned
oraResults.Fields(0)>Value   - Value from first record is returned
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this: loop through the oraResults recordset and read the records:

```
Do until oraResults.EOF
   Response.Write oraResults("firstFieldName")
   Response.Write oraResults("secondFieldName")
   oraResults.MoveNext
Loop
```

[Here's a link](http://www.w3schools.com/ADO/ado_display.asp) that might help.